# Is there a way to set an expiration time for a Django cache lock?

Tags: django, caching, redis, django-cache, django-redis

I have a Django 3.1.3 server that uses Redis for its cache via django-redis 4.12.1. I know that cache locks can generally be set via the following:

```py
with cache.lock('my_cache_lock_key'):
    # Execute some logic here, such as:
    cache.set('some_key', 'Hello world', 3000)
```

Generally, the cache lock releases when the `with` block completes execution. However, I have some custom logic in my code that sometimes does not release the cache lock (which is fine for my own reasons).

My question: is there a way to set a timeout value for Django cache locks, much in the same way as you can set timeouts for setting cache values (`cache.set('some_key', 'Hello world', 3000)`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've answered my own question. The [following arguments](https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis/blob/master/django_redis/client/default.py#L246) are available for `cache.lock()`:

```
    def lock(
        self,
        key,
        version=None,
        timeout=None,
        sleep=0.1,
        blocking_timeout=None,
        client=None,
        thread_local=True,
    ):
```

Cross referencing that with comments from the [Python Redis source](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/lock.py#L73), which uses the same arguments:

```
   ``timeout`` indicates a maximum life for the lock.
    By default, it will remain locked until release() is called.
    ``timeout`` can be specified as a float or integer, both representing
    the number of seconds to wait.
    ``sleep`` indicates the amount of time to sleep per loop iteration
    when the lock is in blocking mode and another client is currently
    holding the lock.
    ``blocking`` indicates whether calling ``acquire`` should block until
    the lock has been acquired or to fail immediately, causing ``acquire``
    to return False and the lock not being acquired. Defaults to True.
    Note this value can be overridden by passing a ``blocking``
    argument to ``acquire``.
    ``blocking_timeout`` indicates the maximum amount of time in seconds to
    spend trying to acquire the lock. A value of ``None`` indicates
    continue trying forever. ``blocking_timeout`` can be specified as a
    float or integer, both representing the number of seconds to wait.
```

Therefore, to set the maximum time period of 2 seconds for which a cache lock takes effect, do something like this:

```py
with cache.lock(key='my_cache_lock_key', timeout=2):
    # Execute some logic here, such as:
    cache.set('some_key', 'Hello world', 3000)
```